# Connecting new GFCI in the middle of a circuit run

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

I have 4 outlet locations in a circuit run.
From left to right, the line feed is directly to outlet location #3.
I want a GFCI to protect **all** 4 outlets, so I want to put the GFCI in location #3.
Can I connect the wires for outlet #2 and outlet #4 directly to the GFCI receptacle, since there are 2 sets of push-in LOAD connecters on the bottom of it?

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to confirm that more than 1 cable can be connected to the receptacle. The receptacle is authentic UL certified with a safety code number, manufactured by Eaton, purchased at Lowe’s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any branch of the circuit whose hot and neutral are plugged into the "Load" terminals, will be protected from that GFCI.

You are required to label those outlets "GFCI Protected" (NEC 110.3(B) and 8(C) of instructions).  Use any labeling method that isn't handwritten.  Also mark "No Equipment Ground" if applicable (NEC 406.4(D)2).

You can attach *any number* of branches to the "Load" terminals.  If you exceed the number of provided lugs, you can simply pigtail.

"Push-in" aka "Back-stabs" are generally not seen on UL-listed GFCI devices; I suspect that's a UL requirement.  Instead they have "screw-and-clamp" or "insert wires; tighten screw to clamp" terminals.  A bit tricky and you have to clamp HARD, but very nice when you get the hang of it.

If you have a GFCI that does have back-stabs, search it *very closely* for a UL, CSA or ETL mark *with 6-8 digit file number*.  If you don't see that, it is a knockoff/counterfeit device (which would defeat the purpose of installing a *safety device*, obviously). Counterfeits are generally not seen in competent retail shops; 99% of them come from mail-order, and the #1 offender is the Amazon Marketplace, which is eBay-tier junk mostly.